# radeon driver suddenly broken

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

So I turned my computer on today, made no major changes yesterday, and get the following errors on boot:

```
[     1.444561] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[     1.444807] si_cp: Failed to load firmware "radeon/PITCAIRN_pfp.bin"
[     1.444883] [drm:si_init [radeon]] *ERROR Failed to load firmware!
[     1.444921] radeon 0000:01:00.0 Fatal error during GPU init
```

Now, my second screen is not recognised, HDMI audio is not working and the graphics are just sub par.

I booted from a live usb to make sure my graphics card wasn't broken, and everything worked as normal.

Both the live usb and my current install appear to be using the same drivers: radeon, as part of xserver packages.

I tried reinstalling all of the amdgpu packages, i tried adding `radeon.dpm=1 invalid` to grub default boot.

Nothing is working. Please any help would be appreciated, this current setup is pretty much unusable for what I need to do.

Comment: Is the file `/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_pfp.bin` there?

Comment: Yes!but it isnt capitalized

Comment: There must be two of them. One in caps.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, so two follow up question:

Where would I find that file and why should it have disappeared in the first place?

Comment: The file is in `linux-firmware` package. It disappeared because you've deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

`/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_pfp.bin` is missing that used to be there.